# If Statement within While Loop - Php/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

So i'm having a bit of bother with a project i'm working on, I took over this from another developer and I haven't done much if/while statements in Php.

But basically this is a Company Timeline element where if the user clicks on a timeline dot it will show the correct image and text to go with it.

So basically there are 5 timeline dots and the issue that is for some reason the same text shows for two of the timeline dots and then the next text for the next two dots. It's also doing something similar with the images.

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated

```html
    <section class="company-timeline-sect">
        <div class="white-to-color-wave" style="background-image: url('<?php echo th_get_img("wave-masks/white-to-color-wave.svg"); ?>');margin-bottom: 80px;"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <?php if (get_field('company_timeline_intro') != "") : ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <?php echo get_field('company_timeline_intro') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (have_rows('timeline_points_repeater') != "") : ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" style="overflow-x: scroll; cursor: grab; cursor: -webkit-grab;" id="bar">
                    <div class="timeline-bar" style="background-image: url('<?php echo th_get_img("/timeline/background-line.png"); ?>');">
                        <div class="row">
    
                        <?php 
                        while (have_rows('timeline_points_repeater')) : the_row(); 
                            $group_parent = get_sub_field('timeline_point_group');
                        ?>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="timeline-dot">
                                    <p><?php echo $group_parent['timeline_point_top_text']; ?></p>
                                    <img src="<?php echo th_get_img("/timeline/timeline-dot.png") ?>" alt="" id="<?php echo $group_parent['id'] ?>" onclick="HideTimelines();ShowTimeline(<?php echo $group_parent['id']; ?>);">
                                    <p><?php echo $group_parent['timeline_point_bottom_text']; ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-hide" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php while (have_rows('timeline_points_repeater')) : the_row(); ?>
                    <?php $group_parent = get_sub_field('timeline_point_group'); ?>
    
                    <?php if ($i == 0) : ?>
                    <div class="col-md-6 hidabletimeline">
                        <img src="<?php echo $group_parent['image']; ?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 hidabletimeline">
                        <?php echo $group_parent['content']; ?>
                    </div>
    
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="col-md-6 hidabletimeline no-display">
                        <img src="<?php echo $group_parent['image']; ?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 hidabletimeline no-display">
                        <?php echo $group_parent['content']; ?>
                    </div>
                    
                    <?php endif;?>
                        
                    <?php $i++;?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is the js

```
// TimeLine
function HideTimelines() {
  let hidabletimeline = document.getElementsByClassName("hidabletimeline");

  for (let i = 0; i < hidabletimeline.length; i++) {
    hidabletimeline[i].classList.add("no-display");
  }
}

function ShowTimeline(i) {
  let hidabletimeline = document.getElementsByClassName("hidabletimeline");
  hidabletimeline[i].classList.remove("no-display");
  hidabletimeline[i+1].classList.remove("no-display");
}
// TimeLine
```

Comment: You need to show us what that `ShowTimeline` function does, that these dot elements call when clicked.

Comment: @CBroe sorry just added that, thanks.

Comment: So what is this `$group_parent['id']` value that it gets passed as a parameter? The elements get un-hidden based on their numeric index - but if that value does not match the order of the elements as they get output, then I don't see why/how this _should_ work.

Comment: So that id is based off of the ID in the Custom Field in the Wordpress backend. But yeah, I honestly have no idea with that. Its out of my knowledge zone. Do you have any idea on what I should change or would you need to see more to understand?

Comment: hey @ryan, its build using a plugin called "Advance Custom fields". the will be a menu in your wordpress admin panel called "custom fields". could you please check it you may find the timeline values in it. or if possible can you please post a pic of custom fields menu? also can you please check your page's backend, maybe the values are added teice..

Comment: It should be enough, if you just provide that function with the appropriate index position from which it should start looking for the two elements to show. Use a loop counter variable, same as you are doing with `$i` in the second loop (lets name it `$k` here, to avoid confusion) - and then pass `$k*2` as parameter to `ShowTimeline()`. Times two, because you want to hide two elements each time, so for the first clicked dot it needs it needs to start at index 0, for the second at 2, etc.

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar Hey! Yeah each timeline point has a value assigned to it, from 0 - 4 for all 5 of the timeline points. Obviously starting on zero.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks very much for explaining. I'm trying to implement what you've said but I'm not sure if i'm doing it right. Is there any chance you could edit the code i've added to show me? I would really appreciate it, thanks again.

Comment: `$k=0;` before that first while loop, `ShowTimeline(<?php echo $k*2; ?>);` inside, and then `$k++;` before the loop body ends ...

Comment: @CBroe - Yeah I just gave that a go and had no luck.. thanks anyway

Comment: Can you show the full code (at least that section), so we can see if you implemented it correctly?

Comment: @CBroe - I've probably implemented it wrong

The code was too long so here is a link - 
https://www.codepile.net/pile/VjAELGjA

Comment: Yes, you placed the `$k` stuff in the wrong place, you added it to the second loop. It needs to be done with the first one - that's where you are outputting the onclick attribute containing the `ShowTimeline(...)` part. Like this, https://www.codepile.net/pile/gyN3pXVp

Comment: @CBroe - It worked, thank you so much. If I could hug you right now, I would. Have a great weekend man.